Hadamard matrix of order 28 via Paley 1 construction
The Paley 1 construction method allows to construct an Hadamard matrix (square matrices with orthogonal columns and entries equal to $1$ or $-1$ ) of order N = q+1 where q = 3 (mod 4) is a prime power:

With $Q$ the corresponding Jacobsthal matrix, $j$ the all-1 column vector of length $q$ and $I$ the $(q+1)×(q+1)$ identity matrix, then the matrix
$$    H=I+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & j^T\\ -j & Q\end{bmatrix} $$
is a Hadamard matrix of size $N=q + 1$.
The Jacobsthal matrix $Q$ is the $q×q$ matrix with rows and columns indexed by elements of the finite field $GF(q)$ such that the entry in row $i$ and column $j$ is $χ(i − j)$ where
$$\begin{aligned}
&&  χ(a)=0 &\text{ if } a=0\\
&&  =1 &\text{ if } a=b^2 \text{ for some non-zero }b\in GF(q) \\
&& =-1 &\text{ if } a \text{ is not the square of any element in } GF(q)
\end{aligned}$$

Based on this definition, I implemented a Matlab script:
N = 28;
q = N-1;

%Squares in the field GF(q)
nonzerosquares = mod((1:q-1).^2,q);

%Construction of Q entrywise
Q = zeros(q,q);
for i = 0:q-1
    for j = 0:q-1
        if mod(i-j,q) == 0
            val = 0;
        else
            if ismember(mod(i-j,q),nonzerosquares)
                val = +1;
            else
                val = -1;
            end
        end
        Q(i+1,j+1) = val;
    end
end

%Construction of H
H = eye(N) + [0 ones(1,N-1) ; -ones(N-1,1) Q];
H'*H

This code works for N=8, N=12, N=20, N=24 (it generates Hadamard matrices) but is not working for N=28 although $q=N-1=3^3$ is a a power of an odd prime as requested in the definition.
Since I want to make this Paley 1 construction works for $N=28$, does anyone know what's wrong with my approach?

You seem to be computing modulo $q$ rather than in the field of $q$ elements. The notions coincide when $q$ is prime but are different otherwise.

$q=N-1$ is $7,11,19,23$ in the cases it works, but $27$ here. So I suspect, you have an error for the finite field of order $27$, which is not $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ as for prime numbers.

I got a -1, but your comments help me, and I thought math.stackechange was done to get some help. So thank you very much @TravisWillse and @DietrichBurde! To compute in the field of q elements (when q is a power of a prime), I suppose it will require many changes to the code ?

The command nonzerosquares = mod((1:q-1).^2,q); computes each square modulo $q$. For prime $q$ this operation computes the square in $F_q$, but if $q$ is not prime, it does not (if $q = p^m$, $m > 1$, then both $0$ and $p^{m - 1}$ have square $0$ modulo $q$, but $0$ is the only element of a field whose square is $0$). So as written your algorithm should work for $N = 8, 12, 20, 24, 32, \ldots$ (OEIS A090658) but not for $N = 28, 244, 344, 1332, 2188, \ldots$ (this sequence doesn't seem to appear in the OEIS); see also OEIS A085760.
To rectify the situation you'll need some way to construct and square the elements of general finite fields $F_q$. SageMath, which more-or-less extends Python, has built-in support for working over finite fields (see SageMathCell, which offers an online interface). The command list(set([x^2 for x in GF(27)])) yields a list of squares in $F_{27}$:
[0, 1, 2*z3, 2*z3 + 1, 2*z3 + 2, z3^2, z3^2 + 2, z3^2 + z3, z3^2 + z3 + 1, z3^2 + 2*z3, z3^2 + 2*z3 + 1, 2*z3^2 + 2, 2*z3^2 + z3 + 1, 2*z3^2 + 2*z3 + 1]
Here Sage realizes the field $F_{27}$ as $F_3[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$, where $p(x) = x^3 + 2 x^2 + x + 1$ is the Conway (i.e. lexicographically first irreducible) polynomial for $F_{27}$ and z3 denotes the image of $x$ under the projection $F_3[x] \to F_3[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$.
Alternatively, SageMath already implements the Paley construction.
The code
from sage.combinat.matrices.hadamard_matrix import hadamard_matrix_paleyI
hadamard_matrix_paleyI(28)

yields
$$
\tiny
\pmatrix{
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{blue}{\!\!1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1} & \color{red}{\!\!-1}
} .$$
